# Use a MsgBox to echo a variable while running the Perl Script Remotely?

Tags: perl

Is this possible?

Using VB.net I am executing a remote perl script. I want a MsgBox to appear on my screen, similar to VBScript.

I tried just doing Win32::MsgBox("Test") but that didn't work.
Is it even possible?

I am executing the script remotely FROM a Windows system to a Unix system.

Comment: "that didn't work" is not a diagnostic message produced by Perl or Windows. In what way did it not work? Was there an error message? An exit code?

Comment: No error message, no exit code. On my windows system, a msgbox didn't open up. I would assume now that I'm looking into it further is because I am executing the perl script on a unix system, it doesn't have access to Win32 functions. I need to find an alternative though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use text-only replacement like this:

```
sub AskYesNo {
    my ($question, $default) = @_;
    print $question, $default ? " [Y/n] " : " [y/N] ";
    my $answer = lc(ReadLine 0);
    chomp $answer;
    return 1 if $answer eq "y";
    return 0 if $answer eq "n";
    return $default;
}
```

It will select default answer "y" or "n" if user presses just Enter.
It may be not pretty, but gets job done and works under any Perl.